# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split' during time conversion in a loop via a .csv column

Tags: python, csv, file, time, multiple-columns

I have a big .csv file having one column time which I need to do a conversion in order to work them later. the timing format is hh:mm:ss.

for example : my data is: input1:

```
Time
0:00:000
0:00:003
0:00:006
0:00:008
0:00:011
0:00:014
0:00:017
```

I am having problems with this bit of code.

```
import csv
with open("input1.csv", 'r') as inf, open("output1.csv",'wb') as outf:
    reader = csv.reader(inf, delimiter=',')
    writer = csv.writer(outf, delimiter=',' )
    for row in enumerate(reader):
        if(len(row) < 0):
                continue
        t = row
        (h,m,s) = t[1].split(':')
        result = int(h) * 3600 + int(m) * 60 + float(s)
        t[1] = result
        writer.writerow(t)
```

output shows error: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'`.
I'm stuck with the conversion.Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: You want to convert to seconds? Which part are you having trouble with?

Comment: output shows error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: When posting a question about code that produces an Exception, always include the complete Traceback - copy and paste it then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`)

Comment: Okay. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, one tip to handle such things. Execute your code in an IDE. E.g. in Spyder, or idle. Then you can inspect the variable in such cases and will immediately see, what was going wrong. In this case it was just, that the reader returns rows and no matter how many columns a row contains, it is always represented as a list. So you send split to the list object and not to a column value.

Answer (score 1):

Fake data - using io.StringIO instead of files.

```
import io, csv
inf = io.StringIO('''Time
0:00:000
0:00:003
0:00:006
0:00:008
0:00:011
0:00:014
0:00:017''')

outf = io.StringIO()

reader = csv.reader(inf, delimiter=',')
writer = csv.writer(outf, delimiter=',' )
next(reader)    # skip header
```

A [csv.reader returns a list](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/csv.html#csv.reader) for each row just like the documentation says.

```
>>> for row in reader:
    print(row)

    
['Time']
['0:00:000']
['0:00:003']
['0:00:006']
['0:00:008']
['0:00:011']
['0:00:014']
['0:00:017']
```

You need to extract the column from the list/row. Assuming the time is in the first column.  If you ran that previous for loop you need to execute `inf.seek(0)` before running the following.

```
inf.seek(0) 
next(reader)    # skip header
for row_number,row in enumerate(reader):
    if(len(row) < 0):
            continue
    (h,m,s) = row[0].split(':')
    result = int(h) * 3600 + int(m) * 60 + float(s)
##    t[1] = result
    writer.writerow((row_number,result))
```

To see the results using my examples:

```
outf.seek(0)
print(outf.read())
```

---

Using your files

```
import csv
with open("C:/Users/Pom/Desktop/input1.csv", 'r') as inf, open("C:/Users/Pom/Desktop/output1.csv",'wb') as outf:
    reader = csv.reader(inf, delimiter=',')
    writer = csv.writer(outf, delimiter=',' )
    next(reader)    # skip header
    for row_number,row in enumerate(reader):
        if(len(row) < 0):
                continue
        (h,m,s) = row[0].split(':')
        result = int(h) * 3600 + int(m) * 60 + float(s)
        writer.writerow((row_number,result))
```

Comment: Thanks for your rply. But this code (3rd part) is not giving any output. Could you please check it again?

Comment: Thank you so much for this. This is very helpful and answers my question.